# Cannot send form data with axios when using interceptors

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using **React** and **axios** to fetch data from API. Everything is working fine until, for some reason, I need to intercept the response and in this case my form data are not sent anymore.

For all classic cases, I'm doing something like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('param1', 'value1');
formData.append('param2', 'value2');
formData.append('param3', 'value3');

axios({
    //...
    data: formData
})
```

So I can see in the request call:

[image]

To use interceptor, I tried without changing the config above like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    //...
    data: formData
});
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    //...
}, (error) => {
    //...
});
instance.request();
```

but the form data is not sent in the request header:

[image]

My 2nd try was to use the [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) parsing and stringifying library but I got the same result

```
const instance = axios.create({
    //...
    data: qs.stringify({
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2',
        param3: 'value3'
    })
});
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    //handle success
}, (error) => {
    //handle error
});
instance.request();
```

My 3rd try was to add a request interceptor by modifying config (add `formData`) before request is sent but I never access the callback function (the `console.log()` line below) and so I got the same result:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    console.log(config);
    // Do something before request is sent
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
});
```

I created [this live running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-allen-bnzw5) to simulate my 3 tries above.

Any feedback about this issue or help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have separation of concerns.

- Create a little function for axios instance creation and export it. Create the instance just once.
- Create a function for configuring the interceptors.
- Move these into separate file/helper.
- Call the interceptor.
- Finally in your component, import the charged up axios instance and use it.

Also note that you are adding form data while `creating` axios instance. Add your form data in your `request interceptor`.

Like this:

```js
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.data = formData;
    return config;
  });
```

**Working copy of your code is here:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-interceptor-isssue-bdd4h?file=/src/axiosInstance.js

**Code snippet:**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("param1", "value1");
formData.append("param2", "value2");
formData.append("param3", "value3");
const headers = { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" };
const method = "post";

export const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
  method,
  headers
});

const interceptors = () => {
  instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.data = formData;
    return config;
  });

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      // do what ever you want with your response
      return response;
    },
    error => {
      //handle error
      console.log("error:", error);
    }
  );
};
interceptors();//call the interceptors function
```